# Media Player - Preload Multiple Clips

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a media player that can load **MULTIPLE CLIPS** at a time.
Just load. Not play.

When you load the program, I was hoping that the user can click "load" and select different files for each of the buttons.

Once the clips have all been loaded, the user can go through and click a "play" button that corresponds with the Load Button.

I also hoped that beside each "play" button, there be a Loop Checkbox (if ticked, it loops the video)

The Program so far:

[image: screenshot]

Current Source:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MediaPlayer
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    MediaPly _mp = null;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            _mp = new MediaPly();
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _mp.LoadFile(openFileDialog1.FileName, this.panel1);
    }




    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            _mp = new MediaPly();
        }
    }
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _mp.LoadFile(openFileDialog1.FileName, this.panel1);
    }




    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            _mp = new MediaPly();
        }
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _mp.LoadFile(openFileDialog1.FileName, this.panel1);
    }



}
}
```

Comment: Can't quite see the question here.  What's not working?

Comment: I can only "load" one clip at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving all clips to the same variable (`_mp`).
Try to save each in a different variable:

```
MediaPly _mp = null;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        _mp = new MediaPly();
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _mp.LoadFile(openFileDialog1.FileName, this.panel1);
}



MediaPly _mp2 = null;
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        _mp2 = new MediaPly();
    }
}
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _mp2.LoadFile(openFileDialog1.FileName, this.panel1);
}



MediaPly _mp3 = null;
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        _mp3 = new MediaPly();
    }
}

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _mp3.LoadFile(openFileDialog1.FileName, this.panel1);
}
```